# libtool installed but not on path after installation

Tags: apt

I am trying to install libtool.  It appears to not be available even after I install it.

Any help valued.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-10:/opt/backend.mydomain.com/HaLVM$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-10:/opt/backend.mydomain.com/HaLVM$ which libtool

ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-10:/opt/backend.mydomain.com/HaLVM$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libtool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libtool*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 826 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 66863 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libtool (2.4.2-1.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...


ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-10:/opt/backend.mydomain.com/HaLVM$ sudo apt-get install libtool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libtool-doc gfortran fortran95-compiler gcj-jdk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtool
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/180 kB of archives.
After this operation, 826 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libtool.
(Reading database ... 66838 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libtool_2.4.2-1.11_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtool (2.4.2-1.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up libtool (2.4.2-1.11) ...


ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-10:/opt/backend.mydomain.com/HaLVM$ which libtool
```

Comment: try `locate libtool` or `whereis libtool`

Comment: what is your PATH?  output of command `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 74):

fixed it

```
sudo apt-get install libtool-bin
```

Comment: I found that `libtool-bin` was not an available package until after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, reboot, then `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 8):

In my Ubuntu LTS, I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

In root of source folder

```
autoconf
autoreconf --install
```

successfully done